# How do I remap a default keyboard combination?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

The shift + 3 combination on my keyboard layout (Irish English, en_IE) by default gives the British currency symbol (£).
Unfortunately there's no easy combination to give a hashtag as far as I can tell.

What's the easiest way of remapping the Sterling symbol to give a hashtag?

Comment: do you mean when you press Shift+3 you want # Symbol?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

take backup of the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ie`

```
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ie /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ie.backup
```

Open the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ie` with gedit

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ie
```

edit the line like below

```
key <AE03> { [            3,    numbersign,            copyright,        threesuperior ] };
```

Save the file, Close and refresh the shell Alt+F2 r enter

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. And I'm guessing that I will be able to replicate this process to add an easy key combination for an em dash also!

Comment: yes you can do same way..